# What is an efficient data structure to find paths in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

Given a tree: we want to support finding paths between nodes and at the same time finding the children of specific nodes

```
          1
        /   \
       2     3
     /  \     \
    4    6     5
   /
  7
```

What is an efficient data structure to find paths between two nodes
4 -> 5 (path is 4 2 1 3 5)

I thought I can model this as a adjacent list and then perform a simple BFS

but at the same time we also want to maintain the order of the nodes since we will have queries of the type
print all children of node 2 ... answer is 4, 6, 7

Do I have to store parent points?
I feel like that I'm missing an important data structure, will disjoint sets help?
any pointers or references to CLRS, algorithms design manual, online resources would help, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Every path between two vertices on a tree goes through their lowest common ancestor (LCA), which is the unique vertex on that path that is closest to the root.  There are efficient data structures for querying the LCA in constant time, but they require a bit of work to implement.  If you do implement them, then starting from each of the two given vertices x and y in turn, you can simply walk back up the tree until you hit the vertex that you already identified by calling lca(x, y).

If you don't want to implement these data structures, and can tolerate runtime and memory usage that is proportional to the depth of the tree (which is very often the case), you can do much the same, but walk all the way back up to the root in each case, storing vertices as you go into a corresponding list (one list for x, one for y).  Once you reach the root, process these lists in reverse order by considering each list's last item, then each list's second-to-last item, etc., looking for the first pair of different vertices (or going "back past the beginning" of one of the lists): the previous vertex is the LCA.

For storing the children in each node, just use the usual representation in addition to the parent pointers.

**[EDIT:** As pointed out by Peter de Rivaz, if you know the depths of the two vertices, then you can get the same time complexity without using LCA data structures as if you used them: simply walk up from the deeper vertex until they are both at the same level, then walk up both in parallel until you hit an identical vertex.  This avoids going all the way to the root.**]**

Comment: If you know the depth of x and y, presumably you can just walk up until they reach the same depth, and then walk up both in parallel until you reach the LCA (avoids going all the way to the root if the path is short)